# Opening a link after manually building it works, but from code it does not

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, python-requests-html

I have a website that uses 2 API calls in order to build the actual link to download a gzip file, the problem is that the headers are changing a lot I think and the cookies too, I tried finding out which ones are the ones that stay the same and in what way the other fields are changing but no luck so far.
The website is [this](http://prices.super-pharm.co.il/)

I'm using the `urlib` library as follows:

```py
request = urllib.request.Request(link, headers = headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the following website to find out the proper headers that should go into the requests you'll do.

- [trillworks](https://sqqihao.github.io/trillworks.html)

Usually, you don't need to send the cookies in the request, but for some reason,, your websites sometimes didn't work without them (or it might be another reason too).

I used this code in order to get the cookie's value:

```py
import http.cookiejar

cookie_value = ""
cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
cookie_processor = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(cookie_processor)
response = opener.open(base_url)
for cookie in cookie_jar:
    cookie_value += f"{cookie.name}={cookie.value},"
cookie_value = cookie_value[:-1]
```

Then I inserted it into the headers I got from the above website:

```py
headers1 = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": f"{cookie_value}",
    "Host": "prices.super-pharm.co.il",
    "Referer": f"{base_url}/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
headers2 = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': f'{base_url}/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    "Cookie": f"{cookie_value}",
}
```

Then I used the following code in order to get the final API URL for the gzip file:

```py
link1 = f"{base_url}{href1}"
request = urllib.request.Request(link1, headers=headers1)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
res = response.read()
_decode = ast.literal_eval(res.decode("utf-8"))
_decode = _decode['href']
link2 = f"http://prices.super-pharm.co.il{_decode}".replace('\/', '//')
request = urllib.request.Request(link2 , headers = headers2)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

And finally you can use the `response` in order to get your file.